# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF"

Tags: oracle

I am doing this

```
DECLARE v_Valid_Cnt NUMBER;

BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt INTO v_Valid_Cnt
FROM
(    
SELECT * FROM TABLE1    
MINUS 
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
);
dbms_output.put_line('CNT'||v_Valid_Cnt);
IF (v_Valid_Cnt = 0) 
THEN    
SELECT 'IFSTMT' FROM DUAL;
ELSE
SELECT 'ELSESTMT' FROM DUAL;       
END IF;
END;
```

I can view the dbms output correctly as 0, On checking If else condition I am getting the error   **PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement**

Comment: I don't actually see an `ELSE` condition above.  Did you mean to include one?

Comment: You have an `END:` before your `IF`. It shouldn't be there. It should be after the `END IF;`. You also don't have an ELSE condition.

Comment: I have updated my question.., why Into clause is expected? Here in my case If cnt =0 then I would do nothing else I will perform Delete and Insert statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a BEGIN -> you've entered into the PL/SQL world.

And IN PL/SQL, you CAN do a SELECT, but it's a SELECT INTO

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/SELECT-INTO-statement.html#GUID-6E14E04D-4344-45F3-BE80-979DD26C7A90)

This works:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
    v_valid_cnt   NUMBER;
    message       varchar2(25);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) cnt
    INTO v_valid_cnt
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                employees
            MINUS
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                emps_excel_copy
        );

    dbms_output.put_line('CNT: ' || v_valid_cnt);
    IF
        ( v_valid_cnt = 0 )
    THEN
        SELECT
            'IFSTMT' into message
        FROM
            dual;

    ELSE
        SELECT
            'ELSESTMT' into message
        FROM
            dual;

    END IF;

-- and don't forget to print your message!
 dbms_output.put_line(message);

END;
```